# VS-code adding spaces between class name which contains hyphens

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, jsx, eslint, prettier

My VSCode is configured with prettier and ESLint settings to make the development easy.

But I am not sure which rule is affecting my JSX class names. Ideally, the class name should be: `test-wrapper`

```
 <i className={style.test-wrapper} />
```

But its getting changed to below on save and causing lot of issues:

```
 <i className={style.test - wrapper} />
```

May i know which rule i should override or modify?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using **dot notation** to access object property (`style.test-wrapper`) only works when the name of the property contains plain letters `a-z`, `A-Z`, digits `0-9` and special characters `$` and `_`. Also, the name cannot start with a digit.

If you want to use character `-` in property name, you can use **bracket notation**:

```
<i className={style['test-wrapper']} />
```

Comment: Im getting problems still that bracket notation is working only with classes without hyphens

Answer (score 1):

For css modules you can define your classes as `test-wrapper` and you can still call the classes as camel case as follows. It worked for me thought might help someone

```
 <i className={style.testWrapper} />
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem via vs code editor
**Setting->open setting ui** 
**setting ui** getting top right corner
 add code on your vs code solve it

```
"editor.formatOnSave": false,
"editor.insertSpaces": false
```

Comment: "Insert Spaces" controls whether VSC inserts spaces when pressing `Tab`.

Answer (score 0):

I opened `Code > Preferences > Settings` and entered `insert space` in the search bar. 30 settings were found. None control inserting spaces around hyphens.

I searched the settings for `hyphen` and `dash`, didn't find anything.

I switched off all 30 `Insert space...` settings. VS-Code continues to insert spaces around hyphens in parentheses.